# In Chef, why are raised exceptions not rescued?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, chef-infra

In Chef, Why does this code not catch the thrown exception in the bash resource?  If I run this code, I never ever get to the python resource even when the exception is thrown. The error is expected, which is why I'm catching it, and then going over to pymongo and fixing it that way.

```
begin
    bash "mongo fix" do
        code "mongo --verbose #{filename}"
        action :run

    end
rescue
    python 'pymongo reconfig'  do
        code "Pymongo does a catch and reconfig"
    end

end
```

And this is the exception output

```
[2013-03-05T20:03:55+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash[mongo fix (noudata::mongo line 77) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '253'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20130305-3916-14xxhn5-0" ----
STDOUT: MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
Tue Mar  5 20:03:55 versionCmpTest passed
Tue Mar  5 20:03:55 versionArrayTest passed
connecting to: test
Tue Mar  5 20:03:55 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Mar  5 20:03:55 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Tue Mar  5 20:03:55 connected connection!
true
{
"errmsg" : "replSetReconfig command must be sent to the current replica set primary.",
"ok" : 0
}
Tue Mar  5 20:03:55 uncaught exception: [object bson_object]
failed to load: /tmp/test.js
STDERR:
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20130305-3916-14xxhn5-0" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20130305-3916-14xxhn5-0" returned 253
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly catching the Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed exception?

Answer (score 6):

The code in the `begin` block makes an instance of a `Chef::Resource::Bash` resource, assigns the resource's `code` and `action` attributes, and adds the resource to `run_context.resource_collection`. The resource is not "run" in any sense. Making an instance of the resource does not raise any exceptions, so the code in the `rescue` block is not run.

Later on, once all of your recipe code has finished running, Chef will loop over the resources in the `run_context.resource_collection`. For each resource, Chef will run the resource's actions. In the case of a `bash` resource, that means running the string given in the resource's `code` attribute. Notice that this happens well after your recipe and all other recipes have finished running, and so this happens well outside of your `begin` block. Any exceptions raised by this resource when its actions are run do not propagate to your `begin` block, because the actions are not called from within your `begin` block, but from well after it.

You can try something like this:

```
bash "mongo fix" do
  code "mongo --verbose #{filename} || python pymongo reconfig"
end
```

Comment: Got it.  Is there a way to catch this exception down below then?  Because python pymongo reconfig is actually hiding about 20 lines of python code.  Actually, is there a way to use Ruby to set up the replica set and reconfig it?  Some constraints for cloud-init require me to use the same script for initial initialization of the replica set and the reconfig to force this node to revert back to the primary.

Comment: You can absolutely use Ruby to configure mongo (once the config file is written and the service is running). You can use the `mongo` gem from within the `block` attribute of a `ruby_block` resource. You can also try the [edelight/chef-mongodb](https://github.com/edelight/chef-mongodb) cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in definition and call definition from the recipe.